# Elastic Search, suggest completion not working

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I've been working on a site that jumped a few versions upgrading ElasticSearch (and the PHP api). I can't get the autocomplete to work for terms, despite everything looking like examples I find online.

Mapping...
`'mappings' => array( '_source' => array( 'enabled' => true ), 'dynamic' => false, 'properties' => array( 'search_term' => array( 'type' => 'text', 'analyzer' => 'myNGramAnalyzer', 'search_analyzer' => 'standard' ), 'search_suggest' => array( 'type' => 'completion', 'analyzer' => 'autocomplete', 'search_analyzer' => 'standard' ), 'week_searches' => array( 'type' => 'integer', ),`

Indexing...
`$params['body'][] = array( 'search_term' => $clean_term, 'search_suggest' => array( array( 'input' => $clean_term, 'payload' => $document, 'weight' => $weight ) ), 'week_searches' => "$week" );`

The search...
`$params['body']['suggest']['autocomplete'] = [ 'text' => $this->search_term, 'completion' => [ 'field' => 'search_suggest', 'size' => self::TERM_RESULT_SIZE, 'fuzzy' => [ 'fuzziness' => 0 ] ] ];`

Response fails, with the reason...
`no mapping found for field [search_suggest]`

In the search, I can change the field to *search_suggest.input* but that gives me the reason...
`Field [search_suggest.input] is not a completion suggest field`

So I'm stumped and hoping for some help into what stupid thing I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What version of ES are you using? and can you show what you get from `GET <index-name>/_mapping`, i.e. the real mapping not the one you think you have

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed me being stupid.
In deleting the index (to redo the mapping) I used the wrong name (our code uses a mix of term and search_term).

It turns out a few hours talking to the developer-duck on my desk wasn't enough. Asking here and then thinking more made me realise what was wrong.